# Using pre_get_posts assign custom post to wordpress editor user

Tags: custom-post-types

I am using pre_get_posts function and i want to assign to editor user. when i logged in to editor user account i used below code.

```
public function pre_get_posts($query){

    if(!$query->is_main_query()) {
      return $query;
    }
    if($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'agency' && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
        if(current_user_can('agency_editor') ){
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $query->meta_query = array(
                'key' => 'agency_to_author',
                'value' => $user->ID,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The function in your example is setup to query all posts with the `agency_to_author` meta value set to the users ID, is this what you are trying to do?  Also, the `current_user_can` function is supposed to take a capability, it looks like you are using the actual role slug, you can find all the built in capabilities here https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities.

Comment: Administrator assign multiple user on single custom post type records and that multiple user ( agency_editor ) and edit only those records which is assing by administrator